# $\zeta:eM\to eR\otimes_R M$ is a group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring, $e\in R, e\neq0$ be an idempotent element (i.e. $e^2=e$). Let $_RM$ be a left $R$-module.

I have to show that
$$
\zeta:eM\to eR\otimes_R M
$$
definded by $em\mapsto e\otimes m$ is a group isomorphism.

It easily proved that it is a group morphism and it is surjective.

My problem is with injectivity: I have to prove that $\zeta(em)=0_{eR\otimes_R M}\Longrightarrow em=0_{eM}$, that is $m=0$.

Now

\begin{align*}
\zeta(em)=0_{eR\otimes_R M}
\Longleftrightarrow e\otimes m=0_{eR\otimes_R M}
\end{align*}
from this, how can I show that $m=0$ (supposing $e\neq0$)?

In general, given two modules $M,N$ (right and left resp.) it is not true that $m\otimes n=0$ iff at least one between $m$ and $n$ is zero (think at $\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z_n$)... but I think in this case, thing are going to be a little bit different.

Can someone help me?

Comment: As an example to hunter's remark, let $A$ be a ring, and let $R := A\times A$ and $M := R$. Then $e := (1,0)$ is an idempotent, but $e\cdot(0,1) = 0\in  eM$ even though $(0,1)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: what needs to be shown is that $em = 0$, not that $m = 0$. (The latter claim won't always be true).

We have a map $eR \otimes M \to R \otimes M = M$ induced by the map $eR \to R$, and this map satisfies $e \otimes m \mapsto em$. It follows that the composition $eM \stackrel{\zeta}{\to} eR \otimes M \to M$ is just the inclusion of $eM$ into $M$ and is in particular injective. Thus $\zeta$ was already injective.

Comment: Hey hunter many thanks. Beginners error. I'm ashamed. Thanks again